# Symfony3 routing not working

Tags: php, symfony

I have an account on codeanywhere.com where I'm starting my journey with symfony3. At my first step I have a problem with routing. Thats my controller:

```
<?php

namespace PracaBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class PracaController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/praca", name="_show")
     */
    public function showAction()
    {
        return $this->render('PracaBundle:Default:praca.html.twig');
    }
}
```

that's what I see under ...codeanyapp.com/app_dev.php/praca

```
No route found for "GET ca"
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? If you need more information, just let me know. Thank you for any sugestions.

Comment: What's your config/routing.yml file looks like ?

Comment: He's defining his route as annotation not yml

Comment: @Mawcel Either way, you would have a record in the `config/routing.yml` file. I believe that there's probably another route which is being matched before this one. @maciej.sz could you please run this line and show us the output `php bin/console router:match /praca`. Also, try to clear your cache before running the command.

Comment: I see what you mean my bad

Comment: `php bin/console debug:router` could help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you call `mysite.com/praca` the error message should be `No route found for GET praca` and not get `ca`.

If i were you i'd check if it works with another pattern or even just /.

In case nothing works try to access the default route of the `DefaultController` generated when you generate your bundle through the console.

Comment: Just for info, using an answer to solicit more info is frowned upon.  Really should be using comments.  The roving down voters are gonna get you.

Comment: I am just giving tips to help find the answer by himself since his question is not very clear, not 'soliciting more info'.But i get your point

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `app/config/routing.yml`:

```
....
praca:
    resource: "@PracaBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: Annotation route definition is just a definition of a route (path, name, bla bla bla...). Even if he uses it, he has to let Symfony know "where are the controller classes that define route definitions located?"